# How Azure Purview to interact with PowerBI

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity, azure-service-principal

The requirement is that Purview scans the PowerBI to fetch a few details from Power BI. Can this is something achieved by managed identity or service principle?

Note, as per Microsoft Azure service account is an old way of doing things. So the recommendation is to use managed identity or service principle. But, didn't get any documentation to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the official documentation:

- [Connect to and manage a Power BI tenant in Microsoft Purview (Same Tenant)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/register-scan-power-bi-tenant?tabs=Scenario1)
- [Connect to and manage a Power BI tenant in Microsoft Purview (cross-tenant)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/register-scan-power-bi-tenant-cross-tenant?tabs=Scenario1)
- [Troubleshoot Power BI tenant scans in Microsoft Purview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/register-scan-power-bi-tenant-troubleshoot)

Hope this help.